# ReactiveSearch: How can I delay/suspend a reactive query until multiple filters have changed?

Tags: reactivesearch

The normal behavior is for `ReactiveBase` to execute a new query with each change in a `react` component, such as a filter.

But in my case, I would like to make multiple filter changes and suspend the reactive auto-query until all changes are made. (Imagine an "Apply Filters" button or similar.)

The practical problem is that the immediate on-change queries cause performance problems or poor UX as the user waits for multiple queries to return as each change is made.

Is there any simple way to do this? I am hacking around with changing the `react` property of other shenanigans, but it would seem simplest (for me at least) to simply turn "auto query" off and only refresh results when I explicitly ask for it.

Comment: could you maybe mess around with the transformRequest parameter?

Comment: maybe, but it would be nice is the auto query had more configurable control. In the absence of that, I've also done things like intercept the "next" query and change it, under certain circumstances. All that gets hard though, as you are trying to detect when things are "settled" as opposed to having a "Refresh" or "Update Results" button which would simply explicitly control the refresh